# Store the unique values of two properties from array of objects into single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, set, javascript-objects

How to get unique values of requesterPractitionerId & performerOrganizationId. I need to stroe the unique values of requesterPractitionerId &  performerOrganizationId in a single array.

```
[ 
    { 
        id: '1043120',
        requesterPractitionerId: '1043119',
    },
    { 
        id: '1043081',
        requesterPractitionerId: '1043080'
    },
    { 
        id: 'e1dceebe-c5ba-46a5-a63a-bff709896af4',
        requesterPractitionerId: 'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',
        performerOrganizationId: '05D0889009',
    },
    { 
        id: '2709842f-41e3-4193-8607-fc34d3d24ec1',
        requesterPractitionerId: 'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',
        performerOrganizationId: '05D0889009'
    } 
]
```

Expected Output:

```
1043119
1043080
e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e
05D0889009
```

I am new to Javascript and struggling with this for a couple of hours. Any help would be realy aapreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

- Use `reduce` to create a set with unique values of the said fields
- Then convert the set to array using `Array.from`

```js
let arr = [{id:'1043120',requesterPractitionerId:'1043119'},{id:'1043081',requesterPractitionerId:'1043080'},{id:'e1dceebe-c5ba-46a5-a63a-bff709896af4',requesterPractitionerId:'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',performerOrganizationId:'05D0889009'},{id:'2709842f-41e3-4193-8607-fc34d3d24ec1',requesterPractitionerId:'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',performerOrganizationId:'05D0889009'}];

let result = Array.from(arr.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(c.requesterPractitionerId) a.add(c.requesterPractitionerId);
  if(c.performerOrganizationId) a.add(c.performerOrganizationId);
  return a;
}, new Set()));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Actually I am using do while loop to get the data. So how can I store the data in single array and checks for duplicate entry in array . Can you please check code? https://pastebin.com/S7Sv6s1M

Comment: You need to move `let newArry = [];` outside the do-while loop. With it inside the loop, for every loop, previous loop values are being lost

Comment: Can you please show me the code. Please check the updated code in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/EPb8kBPp

Comment: ReferenceError: records is not defined error throws

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193760/discussion-between-vishnu-and-nikhil-aggarwal).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate a new [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the properties you need. After that, you can `spread` the set's items inside an array.

```js
const input = [{id:'1043120',requesterPractitionerId:'1043119'},{id:'1043081',requesterPractitionerId:'1043080'},{id:'e1dceebe-c5ba-46a5-a63a-bff709896af4',requesterPractitionerId:'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',performerOrganizationId:'05D0889009',},{id:'2709842f-41e3-4193-8607-fc34d3d24ec1',requesterPractitionerId:'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',performerOrganizationId:'05D0889009'}];

let res = input.reduce((acc, o) =>
{
    if (o.hasOwnProperty("requesterPractitionerId"))
        acc.add(o.requesterPractitionerId);

    if (o.hasOwnProperty("performerOrganizationId"))
        acc.add(o.performerOrganizationId);

    return acc;
}, new Set())

console.log([...res]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Actually I am using do while loop to get the data. So how can I store the data in single array and checks for duplicate entry in array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to iterate `data` and then use `Set` to remove the duplicates

```js
let data = [{
    id: '1043120',
    requesterPractitionerId: '1043119',
  },
  {
    id: '1043081',
    requesterPractitionerId: '1043080'
  },
  {
    id: 'e1dceebe-c5ba-46a5-a63a-bff709896af4',
    requesterPractitionerId: 'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',
    performerOrganizationId: '05D0889009',
  },
  {
    id: '2709842f-41e3-4193-8607-fc34d3d24ec1',
    requesterPractitionerId: 'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',
    performerOrganizationId: '05D0889009'
  }
]


let newArry = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
  newArry.push(item.requesterPractitionerId);
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('performerOrganizationId')) {
    newArry.push(item.performerOrganizationId)
  }
})

let k = Array.from(new Set(newArry));

console.log(k)
```

Comment: Can you please check my code actually i have written in do while loop. https://pastebin.com/S7Sv6s1M But I am getting different result.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple - `Set` and `map`, `reduce` and `filter`:

```js
const arr = [{id:'1043120',requesterPractitionerId:'1043119',},{id:'1043081',requesterPractitionerId:'1043080'},{id:'e1dceebe-c5ba-46a5-a63a-bff709896af4',requesterPractitionerId:'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',performerOrganizationId:'05D0889009',},{id:'2709842f-41e3-4193-8607-fc34d3d24ec1',requesterPractitionerId:'e0a844e4-6c8a-489a-8bd6-1d62267d311e',performerOrganizationId:'05D0889009'}];
const res = [...new Set(arr.map(({ requesterPractitionerId, performerOrganizationId }) => [requesterPractitionerId, performerOrganizationId]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr)).filter(Boolean))];
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```